# Question marked as duplicate, but original does't have valid answer

Tags: discussion, support, reopen-closed, vote-to-reopen

[Change color for one part of placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35683601/change-color-for-one-part-of-placeholder)
This question is marked as duplicate on Stack Overflow, but since there is no valid answer in the original question, should I post my answer there as well even if original question is almost 2 years old?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Question marked as duplicate, but original don't have valid answer

A question can still be a duplicate, even if the other question doesn't have an answer.

Of course, in this case, both questions have answers, so I assume by "valid" answer, you mean "an answer itsgoingdown thinks is correct."

> should I post my answer there as well

Normally, yes. If you have an answer to contribute, you should share it on the master question.

However, in this case, there is little point in doing so, because you've already answered the duplicate question. You would just be copying and pasting your answer, and that doesn't help anybody. If you feel strongly that your answer is useful and should appear on the master question, then flag the duplicate and ask a moderator to merge the two questions. Use the "other" option so you can type a detailed explanation of your request.

> even if original question is almost 2 years old

This isn't a message board: we don't care about age here. If you have a good answer to a question, then you can and should contribute it, regardless of how old the question is.

Comment: A question on the last part. Though this is no message board, sometimes old questions did become irrelevant due to the change of software and/or main stream standard. What would the guideline be if that were the case?

Comment: "A question can still be a duplicate, even if the other question doesn't have an answer." Really? Was that changed at some point?

Answer (score 1):

A viable way is to edit the original question, and make it clear why it's actually not answered in the marked duplicate.

This will push the question in the reopen queue, and after it will (perhaps) reopened, you can answer it.

If you really think your answer gives some important additional aspect, put it at the marked duplicate.